# Why is the sizeof operator not evaluated in a for loop condition?

Tags: c, sizeof

I don't know why the `sizeof` operator is not evaluated in a for loop condition at run time. I am trying this simple code with different C compilers but it always print nothing. But if I replace `sizeof(i)` with `4` then it works fine:

> `for(int i = -2; i <= 4; i++)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    for(int i = -2; i <= sizeof(i); i++)
        printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is , the result of `sizeof()` operator is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type.

Next, in the comparison, `i <= sizeof(i)` as per the usual arithmetic conversion rules, `-2`, which is a signed value, gets promoted to an unsigned value, producing a huge value, evaluating the condition to false. So the loop condition is not satisfied and the loop body is not executed.

Run your program through a debugger and see the values in each step, it'll be more clear to you once you see the promoted values in the comparison.

Comment: This is true if the rank of `size_t` is greater than or equal to the rank of `int`, otherwise the code will work as both values will be converted into `int`. It's the "usual arithmetic conversions" rather than the "arithmetic promotion rules"  which may be confused for "integer promotions".

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` yields a value of `unsigned` type variety (`size_t`). The `i` is converted to that type and the comparison executed as

```
(size_t)-2 <= 4
```

something like `4000000000 < 4`

Answer (score 2):

you need to typecast sizeof(i) into int. that should solve the problem.

so just replace `for(int i = -2; i <= sizeof(i); i++)` with `for(int i = -2; i <= (int) sizeof(i); i++)`

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() returns size_t which is an unsigned type.
You can try this code instead:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=-2,j;
  j=(int)sizeof(i);
  for(i=-2;i<=j;i++)
     printf("HELLO\n");
  return 0;
}
```

You can typecast sizeof() to int.